# jQuery.validator.addMethod and required vs optional

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

For the following code,

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod
(
      "exactlength",

      function(value, element, param) 
      {
           return this.optional(element) || value.length == param;
      },

      jQuery.format("Please enter exactly {0} characters.")
);
```

I understand that

- `value` refers to the input field value
- `element` refers to the input field itself
- `param` refers the attribute value for the rule
- `value.length == param` refers to the actual validation

but I don't quite understand why `this.optional(element) ||` has been included for a required field. Most of the examples that I have seen for `addMethod` seem to have this part of the clause. But why is it compulsory, even for the fields that are `required`.

Secondly, let's suppose I wanted email validation, I would add something like,

```
email: 
{
    required: true,
    email: true,
},
```

I would also add the following,

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod
(
      "minLengthID",

      function(value, element, param) 
      {
           return this.optional(element) || value.length >= param;
      },

      jQuery.format("Please enter more than {0} characters.")
);


jQuery.validator.addMethod
(
      "maxLengthID",

      function(value, element, param) 
      {
           return this.optional(element) || value.length <= param;
      },

      jQuery.format("Please enter less than {0} characters.")
);
```

but I don't understand why `this.optional(element) ||` is necessary here. I would appreciate any directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `minlength` and `maxlength` work perfectly fine with the `email` rule.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        emailaddress: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 30
        }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/arex5q69/](http://jsfiddle.net/arex5q69/)**

Notice however, that you'll need to satisfy the `email` rule *before* the `minlength` and `maxlength` rules are evaluated.  Also notice that a very short email address `a@b.com` is six characters long so your `minlength: 6` rule is satisfied immediately.

Conversely, if you put the `minlength` and `maxlength` rules *before* the `email` rule, then they will be evaluated first.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        emailaddress: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 30,
            email: true
        }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO 2: http://jsfiddle.net/arex5q69/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/arex5q69/1/)**

---

`this.optional(element) ||` as part of your custom rule simply makes your field optional *when this rule is used alone*.

However, when you combine your "optional" custom rule with a `required: true`, it's a moot point since the field would never be optional.

The reason you would put `this.optional(element) ||` in your custom rule, is that it leaves you the ability to use it on fields both with and without the `required` rule.

Otherwise, if you leave out `this.optional(element) ||`, your custom rule will *always* make the field `required` *even when you might not want the field `required`*.

Comment: Thanks for that Sparky. Nice explained, but how do I ensure that the email id before the '@' is between the min and max limits ?

Comment: @Grateful, there is no standard method provided that only checks the part of the email address that comes before the `@`.  You would need to write a custom method that also breaks the `value` apart before checking any lengths... however that is not what you asked in your OP, which was titled, `...required vs optional`.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your answer. Also, I realised that the above question  was more of a follow-up to the original question... is this against the stackoverflow rules ? 

Perhaps I need to be asking this "second follow-up" as a separate question as well :)

Comment: @Grateful, it depends.  Since I cannot fully answer a follow-up question like that within comments, it should probably be posted as another question.  Otherwise, very simple follow-ups that can easily be answered in a comment are usually allowed.

Comment: @Grateful, also please "accept" my answer if it answered your original question.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Sadly, I can't figure out how to receive answers via email and so miss out on stuff sometimes.

Comment: @Grateful, you cannot "get answers via email".  The best that you can do is get one notification every several hours.

Comment: Yes, thank you for being pedantic. I meant receive notifications !

Comment: @Grateful, yes, you cannot get instant email notifications.  Only a summary every 3 hours.